# Running a loop in ansible to loop through scripts

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower

I have an existing ansible playbook that runs via ansible tower.

The setup is as follows.

A wrapper playbook

```
#wrapper.yml

---
  - name: Wrapper PowerShell PB
    hosts: [x,y,z]
    tasks:

    - include_role:
        name: "{{ executeAction }}"
      register: "{{ executeAction }}_log"

    - debug: msg="{{ executeAction }}_log"
```

There is another ansible role defined called runScript.
runScript is also a wrapper playbook that copies a script file which is passed as a parameter, copies it across onto the ansible workspace and then called powershell.exe -file 'theScriptFile.ps1'

It runs a single script using the syntax below, where theScriptFile.ps1 is the script file parameter passed.

```
---
  executeAction: 'runScript'
  script: 'myscript.ps1'
```

#within ansible tower, the objective is to be able to run multiple scripts. Based on my research, this is what I have come up with, which is wrong, I am looking for some guidance here on the right approach.

```
---
executeAction: 'runScript'
loop:
  - 'script1.ps1'
  - 'script2.ps1'
loop_control:
loop_var: ExecuteThisFile
script: '{{ ExecuteThisFile }}'
```

In this example, I get an error from Tower that the variable ExecuteThisFile is not defined.

This however works.

```
---
executeAction: 'runScript'
script: 'script1.ps1'
```

The constraint is that, it only runs a single script. by wrapping it into a loop. multiple scripts can be executed.

Having read the documentation here https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html

It looks as though there needs to be an inner & outer loop.

To me, it looks like this.For easy reading, I have placed them in a single line. When I have tried this logic from tower, its come back with a syntax error.

```
executeAction: runScript' script 'script1.ps1'
executeAction: runScript' script 'script2.ps1'
executeAction: runScript' script 'script3.ps1'
```

Comment: Can you combine your two questions to one ([How can one call multiple roles within Ansible Tower?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67735822/)) and provide more description what is not working or you are expecting?

Comment: Thank you. I have now combined the question as i thought I was dealing with 2 types of issues. I have also taken the opportunity to refine the question.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is creating multiple roles and each role would refer to a script or two. This removed the need to have a loop.

Within ansible tower,I then created a wrapper playbook that calls the roles.